# How i can handle global event of application android

Tags: android, passwords

I'm work on screen locker for my application. User set password for application (in app setting). Then password is enable after press button Home or Back (in first start activity in stack), user most see lock dialog (extends from Dialog class) on screen, and if password is true unlock screen.
How i can realizate handle global application events in general application without realizate checking for all activities in them
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a class extend it from Application and in that Class implement your business logic

and in your Manifest file in application

```
android:name="com.PackageName.MyApplication"
```

MyApplication is Your class Name that is Extended from Application

Comment: Hi, thank for answer. But how i can realizate, for example, then user press Home Button event & after open app event on the screen (back to same screen)?

Comment: now the second options is you need to Use OnResume method of your class and pop your dialog from that class